# interfaceをObject.keysで回して値を更新したい

Tags: javascript, typescript

javascriptからTypeScriptへの移行を行っています。

javascriptでは下記のようにobjectのkeyを用いて部分変更ができましたが
Typescriptでは型が怒られるため実現できていません。
Typescriptではどう逆立ちしても無理でしょうか？
巨大なobjectの一部を更新するロジックがかなり多いため、なんとか実現したいのですが。。。

**javascript**

```
let profile = {
    name: 'てすと太郎',
    age: 30,
    tel: '090-0000-0000'
}

updateProfile(pram) => {
    Object.keys(pram).forEach((key) => {
        profile[key] = pram[key]
    })
}

updateName() => {
    // nameだけ書き換えたい
    updateProfile({ name: 'てすと花子' })
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
interface Profile {
    name: string
    age: number
    tel: string
}

let profile: Profile = {
    name: 'てすと太郎',
    age: 30,
    tel: '090-0000-0000'
}

updateName() => {
    // nameだけ書き換えたい
    updateProfile({ name: 'てすと花子' })
}


updateProfile(pram: object) => {
    // keyの型で怒られる
    Object.keys(pram).forEach((key) => {
        profile[key] = pram[key]
    })

    // keyof使って見てもダメ
    Object.keys(pram).forEach((key) => {
        const v:keyof Profile = key
        const name = profile[v]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

もしObjectの構造が1次元であるならば、`Partial`とSpread Operatorを使うと次のように書くことができます。

```
interface Profile {
    name: string
    age: number
    tel: string
}

let profile: Profile = {
    name: 'てすと太郎',
    age: 30,
    tel: '090-0000-0000',
}

const updateProfile = (params: Partial<Profile>) => {
    profile = { ...profile, ...params };
}

const updateName = () => {
    updateProfile({ name: 'てすと花子'})
}

updateName();
console.log(profile)
```

### 参考

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt

Answer (score 0):

学習中の身ですが

```
interface Profile {
    [key: string]: string | number
    name: string
    age: number
    tel: string
}
const updateProfile = (params: Partial<Profile>) => {
    profile[key] = pram[key]!;
}
```

とするのはどうでしょう。